# What are viable substitutes for Raspberry Pi to run Octoprint or similar software for Prusa i3 MK3S+?

Tags: prusa-i3, octoprint, raspberry-pi

Where I live, Raspberry Pi is currently* either unavailable, at prices 3 times higher than a year before, or sold online as "untested". Or straight up as not working. So I am not getting one.

At the same time, I'd love to be able to set up Octoprint or similar platform. Are there any alternatives that are not like out of stock worldwide? What I'm looking for is:

1. Ability to send prints using wireless network
2. Ability to monitor prints using webcam / embedded camera
3. Ability to monitor temperatures, get filament runout alarms etc
4. Ability to stop print in case of a fail

---

* end of 2022

Comment: https://all3dp.com/1/best-raspberry-pi-alternatives/

Comment: @0scar this list is useless. All of the boards listed costs 2~3 times more on Amazon that it says on the list. If at all available. Thus, these are not alternatives to the Raspberry Pi. They are just as overpriced and hard to get as original.

Comment: Would https://github.com/luc-github/ESP3D work? You'd need a serial port on the printer, rather than USB, but perhaps you could use this for a print controller and an ESP-Cam board as a camera. It would be about $14 in hardware, all told.

Comment: I use an orangepi to run octoprint. Works great

Answer (score 2):

A recent post on Reddit directed me to a possible alternative. The link given was for a YouTube video titled "[Armbian, Octoprint and Octodash install on Libre Renegade (Raspberry Pi alternative board)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Dt5RHkIppQ&t)" from The feral engineer.

The single board computer listed in the video is the [Libre Computer Board ROC-RK3328-CC](https://a.co/d/a3eLsMP) available on Amazon (US) for $50 USD.

The feral engineer did mention that he had a few problems getting things to work but was successful in the end. He does give the major steps for doing the installation and overcoming some of the errors that popped up.

For a list of **all** possible single-board computer (SBC), module (SoM) and Linux-supported development boards see [Board-DB](https://hackerboards.com/).

---

Another alternative I have recently come across is the Makerbase MKS  Pi Board. It is sold through [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BHZ7TBQB) (85 USD) and [Aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004417871231.html) (55.79 USD) and is a great alternative due to the Raspberry Pi shortage.

The MKS Pi can run a standard Armbian OS but Makerbase supplies an OS image with klipper and kiauh baked in. An install [tutorial](https://3dpandme.com/2022/09/16/tutorial-mks-pi-klipper-install/) by 3DP and me provides easy-to-follow instructions. This SBC is probably the easiest to setup.

Comment: Good point. Sadly, this board is "currently unavailable" at the link you posted and in shops in my country.

Comment: @Mołot I have added another possible alternative.