# Viability of Raspberry Pi 400 as Octoprint Server

Tags: octoprint, raspberry-pi

This is a follow up question for [What are viable substitutes for Raspberry Pi to run Octoprint or similar software for Prusa i3 MK3S+?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/20196/20803)

I was able to grab Raspberry Pi 400 for around $70, so [at MSRP](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-400-the-70-desktop-pc/), and about half of the current pi 4b prices nowadays. Good deal given shortages, so I ordered it when it was available, and only now I started to think if I can really use it.

Thus, are there any special challenges to using Raspberry Pi 400 as OctoPrint server, and does it have any benefits over regular Pi 4B? Is there any ready-made manual about it I could use?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended hardware for OctoPi is [listed](https://octoprint.org/download/) as:

> Recommended hardware: Raspberry Pi 3B, 3B+, 4B or Zero 2. Expect print artifacts and long loading times with other options, especially when adding a webcam or installing third-party plugins.

Now if we compare the specification of the two Pi units:

| Raspberry Pi | Processor | RAM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [400](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-400-unit/) | BCM2711 quad-core Cortex-A72 @ 1.8GHz | 4GB LPDDR4-3200 |
| [4B](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/specifications/) | BCM2711 quad-core Cortex-A72 @ 1.5GHz | 1GB, 2GB, 4GB, 8GB LPDDR4-3200 |

So they are very close in capabilities. The 4B has a slightly slower processor but does have the ability to have more RAM. The 400 does come with a keyboard but its feasibility would depend on your usage (probably not much for OctoPi).

Given the slight disparity in specs, the Raspberry Pi 400 should work fine for OctoPi.

Comment: So I can assume that, other than processor and RAM, these two are similar enough to work as drop-in replacements, and look the same for software? I have no experience with Raspberry, so I don't know.

Comment: Correct. There are other SBCs (single-board computers) that also work such as the Orange Pi, Banana Pi, Rock Pi, etc. they all use similar architecture so the OS should work. I don't have experience with the Raspberry either, but I have used different computers and OSes in the past.

Answer (score 0):

While the server will work, there are some challenges.

Raspberry Pi 400 lacks the camera and screen connectors, specifically:

- 2-lane MIPI DSI display port
- 2-lane MIPI CSI camera port

so you can't use Pi screens and camera modules. You need to find compatible USB webcam if you want to make time lapse of your print or stream your build to oversee it. If you want to add a touch screen, you need to use HDMI+USB one, as most of the screens dedicated for Pi won't work without DSI port.

Pi 4b has:

- 2 × USB 3.0 ports
- 2 × USB 2.0 ports

Pi 400:

- 2 × USB 3.0
- 1 × USB 2.0

One of these will be, of course, occupied by the printer, so if you want to connect a touchscreen and webcam, with 4b you still have up to three usb ports free, when with 400 you are all out.

Built-in keyboard is somewhat redeeming quality, especially if you are old time console jockey and don't need a mouse or touchscreens, and 20% faster CPU is nothing to sneeze at if you want to use AI plugin to oversee your print. For end users not interested in any kind of hardware hacking, 400 being already assembled with case and cooling is a great benefit, too.

**In summary**: it's compatible, faster and more convenient for end users, but less hackable. It's also significantly cheaper during 2022/2023 Pi Shortage, sometimes being available at MSRP and in stock.

Comment: As for the number of USB ports, I don't think the 400 would be a deal-breaker since you could always connect a USB hub for lesser demanding devices.

Comment: @agarza sadly, keyboard is wired to USB port at the trace level, so sharing this least demanding device with mouse, touchscreen etc doesn't seem possible. And you don't want to have printer on the hub. This may not be a deal-breaker, but it is a disadvantage. Overall, it's two specialised and one generic port less, I believe notable difference worth considering before buying.