# Is there a distribution of OctoPrint for Raspberry Pi 4b that's not headless?

Tags: octoprint, raspberry-pi, octopi

I finally managed to get my Raspberry Pi 4b and make it work with a touchscreen. Previously I was using [Pi 400](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/20278/20803) but I want to move to the touchscreen setup.

Is there a distro of Octoprint for Raspberry that is not headless, and instead uses the screen? I'm OK with a fullscreen browser with https://localhost.local open on it, I don't fancy trying to add everything from scratch.

[image: Photo of Raspberry Pi 4b with a screen]

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using [OctoPi](https://github.com/guysoft/OctoPi). There is no such version that I'm aware of. However, you could relatively quickly run a [OctoPrint container](https://github.com/OctoPrint/octoprint-docker) using [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/raspberry-pi-os/) on the Raspberry Pi or install it on the without a Docker container on the Pi, for example, using [Debian OS](https://raspberrytips.com/install-debian-on-raspberry-pi/) or maybe even on Raspbian.

This way, you have an OS with GUI and can open the browser and access the local OctoPrint GUI in the local browser. I don't know if this will cause much overhead in terms of performance, which could affect your prints if it's lagging too much. It probably will need active cooling or at least a heatsink.

*Nice display. I agree that it would be nice to see an OctoPi version with a local GUI, preferably optimized for a small (touch) screen; perhaps you can request that feature on GitHub and refer to this question.*